# Get raw SAML response from omniauth-saml failure callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, saml-2.0

I am using omniauth-saml 1.3.1 with omniauth 1.2.2 in rails 4.2. It works well with my test identity provider set up at openidp.feide.no (a nifty tool for those setting up a SAML service provider). It even works in production.

Now I am trying to get an IdP set up with a client of mine. When the user visits /auth/saml, they are directed to the client's IdP as expected. The user is able to use their email/pw to login.

The IdP then responds to my SP, but omniauth is redirecting to the failure callback.

As seen [here](https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/saml.rb#L57), I get an error message "invalid_ticket". However, the error itself isn't getting passed to my failure controller action in `env["omniauth.error"]`, as I read it should somewhere (unfortunately I can't find that documentation right now).

I'm hoping somebody will have some advice as to how I can figure out what is causing the "invalid_ticket" to happen. Is there perhaps a way to see the raw SAML response from the IdP?

I should note that I need to find this information in production because the client's IdP points to our production SP and I can't convince them to point it somewhere I can do some more extensive testing (like my localhost dev machine). I can, however, write in some more logging or Honeybadger exception reporting if that will help.

Currently, I am reporting to Honeybadger all `env["omniauth.*"]` values and `params` when omniauth redirects to the failure route, but I am not getting any information further than `Omniauth message: invalid_ticket`.

A big thank you to anyone who can help me go in the right direction here!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try adding other environments to failure_raise_out_environments:

```
OmniAuth.config.failure_raise_out_environments = ['development', 'staging', 'production']
```

to your initializer. You will get meaningful error messages in your log or Honeybadger.

These errors are by default raised only in development environment.

Comment: I'll be getting into figuring this stuff out soon, and I will certainly give this a try when I get there. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: After spending hours debugging this I've stumbled upon this suggestion and it helped! Thanks a lot!